# Upgrading ASP.NET MVC2 project to MVC3 and using mixed View Engines

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Can I upgrade my MVC2 project to MVC3 and continue to use my ASPX views, AND at the same time start writing some new views in Razor?

More specifically, Can I take an ASPX view page, and a Razor control in it?  Would such a thing be possible?

Any other things one should look out for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can definitely mix view engines across totally separate views. As for putting Razor "controls" in an ASPX page, if you use RenderPartial, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would watch out for is that if you use **Master Pages** then you may end up duplicating them for both view engines. I had a good ol' WebForms Master Page, used by all my regular .aspx content files, but creating a new view using Razor means I have to use a duplicate Razor layout page alongside that old Master Page.

I haven't looked into it too much, but at first try I get '*The file "~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" could not be rendered, because it does not exist or is not a valid page.*' and certainly there's nothing in [Scott Gu's blog entry introducing Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) to suggest you can combine them, but I could be all wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx

For how to mix view engine master pages...